# Argument error within Pine Script strategy

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to create an overnight gap trading backtester. The idea is to have the algo enter long at 3:59 pm before market close and exit long at 9:00 am after market open when the long condition is met. In this case, the long condition is simply an overnight gap of greater than 10% over the past two previous opens. I figured the easiest way to do this would be to define the session hours and create a variable for marketOpen and marketClose at the desired entry and exit times. The lines of code doing this are not giving me errors so I believe they are correct. However, when I use these variables in the following lines of code, which serve to calculate daily gap percentages, I get an argument error saying I cannot call 'operator -' with arguments. I have tried everything I could think of, from adding input functions to the gapSize 1 & 2 lines, adding quotation marks, parentheses, etc. I am confident if I can get the algo to accept these variables the strategy will work. Any help and/or advice is greatly appreciated.

```
'''
//@version=4
strategy(title="Gap Strategy", overlay=true)

t = time(resolution=timeframe.period, session="0930-1600")
marketOpen = input(defval="0930", title="marketOpen", type=input.time)
marketClose = input(defval="1559", title="marketClose", type=input.time)

gapSize1 = ((marketOpen[2] - marketClose[3]) / marketClose[3]) * 100
gapSize2 = ((marketOpen[1] - marketClose[2]) / marketClose[2]) * 100
longCondition = (gapSize1 > 10) and (gapSize2 > 10)

if (longCondition)
    strategy.order(id="buy", long=true, when=marketClose[1])
    strategy.order(id="sell", long=false, when=marketOpen)

'''
```

Comment: If you provide a full scenario for the study, I will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are three errors in your script. First, you are trying to apply the history operator `[]` to input variables `marketOpen` and `marketClose`. The history operator `[]` is only applicable for series types. Second, you have defined the variables `marketOpen` and `marketClose` of type `input.time`, and you are trying to calculate the price gap from their values. Third, the condition `longCondition` for entering a long position will be checked earlier than the time you specified 3:59pm.